# Solution to y*ln(y)=x*exp(x)

Tags: mathematical-physics

Can anyone please help me with a close-form explicit solution to
$y\times\ln(y)=x\times\exp(x)$
?
Please note that $y=\exp(x)$ is not the answer I am looking for. The equation actually looks like this $y=\exp(x/y*\exp(x))$

Comment: Why not $y = e^{x}$?. If you take $y = e^{x}$, then 

$yln(y) = e^{x}ln(e^{x}) = e^{x}x$

Comment: This is the spiral equation created by picking those points  on the spiral y=exp(x) with equal interval, say, one point per period. The physics is R=R0*exp(k*theta) where theta =omega*time. To simply, I let R0=1, k=1.

Comment: "$y=\exp(x)$ is not the answer I am looking for": why do you reject a correct answer ???

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask for solutions which are not obvious or not already known. In math we ask for *nontrivial* solutions all the time so I'm confused by the comments to this question.

Comment: You would get better feedback by explaining this first. We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $y=e^t$, the equation reads

$$te^t=xe^x.$$

An obvious solution is $t=x$. Anyway, for $t<0$, the LHS function is not invertible, and you need the two branches of Lambert's function.

$$t_0=W(xe^x)=x,\\t_1=W_{-1}(xe^x).$$

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the Lambert's function!